# how to perform automatic type conversion in dynamic argument parsing

Tags: python, dictionary, types

Most of my python codes I send a (sometimes long!) list of arguments to, which I know how to parse using getopt. All well and good so far...

However I find it tiresome to type out a long if-then-else structure to pass all the arguments to a list of variables (usually of the same name as the passed argument), so I wanted to write a function that simply dynamically accepts arguments and places them in dynamical variable names, which seemed easiest to do using a dictionary, so that the pre-defined dictionary provided the default possible option list as well as default argument values.

I did this in the following way:

```
import getopt, sys

def get_args(runpars):
    """routine to dynamically accept arguments"""
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"h",[key+"=" for key in runpars])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print ('Use these arguments ',runpars)
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        runpars[opt[2:]]=arg

    return(runpars)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # default argument values:
    runpars={"a":1,"animal":"cat","f":3.3}
    runpars=get_args(runpars)
    print(runpars)
```

This essentially works:

If I pass an argument not in the dictionary, it bombs as intended with the key list:

```
getopts_test.py --a=4000 --animal="dog" --c=2.1 --dfrfrfr=23
Use these arguments  {'a': 1, 'animal': 'cat', 'f': 3.3}
```

If I pass some arguments it correctly overrides my options as desired

```
getopts_test.py --a=4000 --animal="dog" 
{'a': '4000', 'animal': 'dog', 'f': 3.3}
```

BUT! as arguments are all passed as strings, my type has now changed to a string...  In my old fashioned clunky if-then-else manually parsing, I of course would convert each argument manually with e.g.

```
param=int(arg)
```

etc etc, but now I can't do this.  So my questions is, is there a way somehow of testing the original dictionary key type and using that to convert the argument from a string.

I essentially want to find some "as_type" method, like

```
runpars[opt[2:]]=arg.as_type(original key this opt matched)
```

Comment: It is recommended to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) instead of getopt. Maybe you convert to argparse and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a really neat way of solving this using `argparse`. You can take advantage of the [`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object) object which can be passed to the [`parse_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) method to better handle the defaults. The idea is simple: instead of creating a new namespace object from the passed arguments and then augmenting it with the defaults, simply pre-create a namespace object from the defaults, and have `argparse` update it with the passed arguments.

This will reduce your code a bit:

```py
def get_args(defaultpars):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dynamic arguments')
    namespace = argparse.Namespace(**defaultpars)

    # add each key of the default dictionary as an argument expecting the same type 
    for key, val in defaultpars.items():
        parser.add_argument('--'+key, type=type(val))
    
    parser.parse_args(namespace=namespace)

    return vars(namespace)
```

Comment: much nicer, I found my overwriting with a new namespace a bit clunky in fact. I really like this method, as I just pop this code in a module to load and from now on I simply define a dictionary and can handle all command line options flexibly with 2 lines of python... :)

Comment: @AdrianTompkins yep, Python can be magical sometimes ;D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Wolfgang Kuehn for his pointer to argparse.  That has the useful "type" option in add_argument, which solved my problem!

So here is my new solution written from scratch using argparse:

```
import argparse

def get_args(defaultpars):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dynamic arguments')

    # add each key of the default dictionary as an argument expecting the same type 
    for key,val in defaultpars.items():
        parser.add_argument('--'+key,type=type(val))
    newpars=vars(parser.parse_args())

    # Missing arguments=None need to be overwritten with default value
    for key,val in newpars.items():
        if val==None:
            newpars[key]=defaultpars[key]
    return(newpars)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # default values:
    runpars={"a":1,"animal":"cat","f":3.3}
    runpars=get_args(runpars)
    print(runpars)
```

giving the correct types in the resulting dictionary:

```
getopts_test.py --a=4000 --animal="dog" 
{'a':4000, 'animal': 'dog', 'f': 3.3}
```