# how to handle lists in automatic argument parsing with argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

[I've written the following module that handles arguments automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367210/how-to-perform-automatic-type-conversion-in-dynamic-argument-parsing) for all my python codes, whereby I define a dictionary of my program parameters and then argparse uses this to set the command line arguments and the argument type when parsing the call sequence:

```
import argparse

def get_args(pars):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dynamic arguments')

    # add each key of the default dictionary as an argument expecting the same type 
    for key,val in pars.items():
        parser.add_argument('--'+key,type=type(val))
    newpars=vars(parser.parse_args())

    # Missing arguments=None need to be overwritten with default value
    for key,val in newpars.items():
        if val==None:
            newpars[key]=pars[key]
    return(newpars)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # default values:
    pars={"a":1,"animal":"cat","f":3.3}
    pars=get_args(pars)
    print(pars)
```

This works fine for parsing floats, integers and strings...

```
python3 test.py --f 2.1
{'a': 1, 'animal': 'cat', 'f': 2.1}
```

but now I want to add an argument that can be a list of numbers, e.g. say my default pars dictionary is this:

```
pars={"a":1,"animal":"cat","f":3.3,"l":[1]}
```

Now this happens:

```
python3 test.py --l [1,2,3]
{'a': 1, 'animal': 'cat', 'f': 3.3, 'l': ['[', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ']']}
```

That's not what I want, I want to get a list of numbers.  In the past when I handled arguments one by one manually I would get around this by using

```
import ast 
val=ast.literal_eval("[1,2,3]")
[1, 2, 3]
```

But I can't use ast.literal_eval on each argument as it fails when not passed strings containing numerical arguments, so I thought to try this:

```
    try:
       parser.add_argument('--'+key,type=type(ast.literal_eval(val)))
    except:     
       parser.add_argument('--'+key,type=type(val))
```

and define the default list as

```
l="[1]"
```

this then returns <class 'list'> for the list argument, but how do I pick that up to conditionally use ast.literal_eval in the parsing ?

Comment: The `type` parameter is supposed to be a function.  It does not specify a class.

Comment: I tried to tighten my language in the question, I'm referring there to the result of the type function in fact, it give me <class 'list'>, am I misunderstanding the point?

Comment: `type=type(val)` only works when `type` is also a function that produces what you want.  `int` and `float`  work. `bool` and `list` don't.  When using `nargs`, the type function is applied to each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an argument as a Python list is a bit "annoying" as all arguments are strings so you will need to parse it as a list. If you are willing to compromise on passing list as space-separated arguments, like `--l 1 2 3`, then one possible way can be to use [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs). Just add a `try/except` block in your loop that will check if the argument is iterable:

```py
for key, val in pars.items():
    try:
        typ = type(val[0])
        nargs = "+"
    except TypeError:
        typ = type(val)
        nargs = None

    parser.add_argument('--'+key, nargs=nargs, type=typ)
```

A few notes:

- This allows any length of list to be passed. If you want to limit the size as the list from the dictionary, just change to `nargs = len(val)`.
- This can only allow homogenous lists - all objects inside must be of the same type.
- I used `nargs = None` and not `nargs = 1` because the latter will actually make the argument a ***list of 1 item***, while the former will pass the argument as a single object.

---

Embedding the above in your code (and using the second `par`, below for readability) will result:

```
pars = {"a": 1, "animal": "cat", "f": 3.3, "l": [1]}

>>> python3 test.py --f 2.1 --l 1 2
{'a': 1, 'animal': 'cat', 'f': 2.1, 'l': [1, 2]}

>>> python3 test.py --f 2.1 --l 1 2.2
test.py: error: argument --l: invalid int value: '2.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `type` parameter is supposed to be a function (`callable`) that takes a string, and returns a value, or raises an error.

Of builtin functions, `int` and `float` are about the only useable ones:

```
In [40]: int("12")
Out[40]: 12
In [41]: float("12.3")
Out[41]: 12.3
```

Others like `list` or `bool` don't return what naive users expect:

```
In [42]: list("[1,2,3]")
Out[42]: ['[', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ']']
In [43]: bool("False")
Out[43]: True
```

Thus if you want to accept '--flag False' (instead of using the 'store_true' `action`), you need a custom function

```
def mybool(astr):
   if astr in ['False', 'no', 'No']:
       return False
   elif ...
```

The intended way of accepting lists is to use the `nargs` to specify how many.

```
$python myscript.py --foo [1,2,3] --bar a b c --baz [1 2]
```

is translated into `sys.argv` as

```
['myscript.py', '--foo', '[1,2,3]', '--bar', 'a', 'b', 'c', '--baz', '[1', '2]']
```

`nargs='+'` will handle the '--bar' case, but not the others.

'--foo' could be handled with `type=ast.literal_eval`, or maybe `json.loads`.  But that bypasses the safeguards that `argparse` provides with `nargs` and `type=int`.